# How is a list persisted back to the controller in MVC3 with Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to do a simple messaging page, and would like a list of recipients that could be modified in place.

So for example:
So the user is at a document, and wants to message other users of that document.

Click message button

Message screen comes up with list of recipients populated already from the ViewModel

User clicks X to remove one or more recipients

User types message

User clicks Submit

Controller receives a model with the message filled in and a list of recipients

How do I ensure that list is the modified list?

Answer (score 1):

Get your html to look something like this:

```
<form ... blah blah ...>
    <ul>
        <li>
            recipient 1
            <input type="hidden" name="theParameterInControllerAction.Recipients[0]" value="1" />
        </li>
        <li>
            recipient 2
            <input type="hidden" name="theParameterInControllerAction.Recipients[0]" value="2" />
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <textarea name="theParameterInControllerAction.Message" ... blah blah ... ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value"click me" />
</form>
```

Set up your model and controller to accept the form according to how I laid out those `name` attributes.  Then, use javascript to remove li as you need in place.  Then, you have two choices:

1. find an MVC model binder that binds to lists even if the indices are out of order (because you may remove recipient 2 and then your controller will see 0,2,3,4,...)
2. use javascript to intercept the post event of that form and re-write the `name` attributes of the hidden inputs above

Hope that was clear, was kind of rushing while I wrote it.